# goto-file (gf) prioritize directory instead of filename

Tags: vim

I'm trying to configure `gf` to open files under the cursor.
It works always... almost.
I found an issue when the text under the cursor has unfortunately a corresponding directory. In that case, `netrw` plugin is opened.
Let me give you an example. I am in this code:

```
    [...], MyObject myobject, [...]
```

I am over `MyObject` and press `gf`.
Unfortunately I have in a folder:

```
    myobject       <-- a directory
    MyObject.java  <-- the file to open
```

`netrw` is activated.

I tried to check doc to tinker a little bit (`suffixesadd`, ...), but probably I am missing how to do it properly.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987380/vim-gf-opens-directories-not-files), but it is a little bit different in my opinion because in that case the match of the text and the directory were the only 1st one and it was perfect.

Any help?
P.S. what I am trying to do is creating a small vim plugin that could be used to navigate Java projects based on Maven (it's called [vim-java-maven](https://github.com/sixro/vim-java-maven/)).
Just for learning VIM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As silly as it may sound, Vim considers directories as valid targets so…

- `:help 'suffixesadd'` doesn't help because the directory name is an exact match,
- `:help 'includeexpr'`, which is only invoked if there is no match, is not invoked since there is a match.

That behaviour is hardcoded and there is no way to affect it at runtime. The only solution is to write your own `Gf()` that handles directories more sensibly and map it to `gf`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl.
I have 3 questions on vim answered all by you :) I mentioned you at the end of [this colorscheme](https://github.com/sixro/vim-mnmlight) for your help. Thanks